# Creating a Simple screen saver in Adobe Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I'm designing a simple information kiosk for a  client using Edge Animate rather than flash. 
Essentially what I want to do is when the user does not touch the stage for 2-3 minutes a symbol is revealed, essentially a screen saver that when clicked returns the user to the home screen.

I've had success executing the symbol, but not setting the variable or resetting the time when the stage is retouched or clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is set up your objects or symbols on your stage and set them to lets say time of 0:00 and then set those objects to "On" in the upper left hand settings, underneath the object "Name".  Now go to the place in the time line you want it to switch to your screen saver lets says 2:30 and now switch the same setting to "Off".  Move the timeline a few mil seconds and make a new Symbol this will be your screen saver and set its setting to "On".  Right click on this symbol and select Open Actions for "yourSmybolName" and add an action "click" and "onmouseover" and for each of those use the code "sym.play(0);" this will cause the timeline to start at time 0:00 any time the symbol is clicked or moused over.  Now click ctrl t and add a sym.stop(); action in the frame where you screen saver symbol starts, you don't have to do this step but I think its good practice.  I think this should solve your problem.

Here is a link to the project I made if you would like to see an example.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/76edl5n3u6wa1ym/screensaver.zip